# How to fix "Unable to save file" when trying to save file in windows

Tags: windows, file, visual-studio-code

I have created my `index.html` and working on it, it works fine as expected. but when i open it after 2 or 3 days and after working on it i save this file using `ctrl + s`. it shows me this error several times and when i restart my pc this issue solves but after some times it appears again.
[image]

First i thought that this is the issue in vs code but when i open this file in notepad it errors same on notepad too.
[image]

Comment: how do you serve it from node? Could it be that node opened it and did not close? you can use [some tool](https://serverfault.com/a/1980/550521) to see which process keeps it open.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny i am not using its a simple html page

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny this problem is only happening with html files not css and js file